# Tmux - How to increase timeout for chain commands and keystrokes in tmux

Tags: tmux

##### Description

When used <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd> . It will show you numbers and wait brief moment for further input (if any). **I want to increase this time, timeout or something to 2s**

I guess it will also affect commands to swap panel and other used to customize layout.
That is ok, I would like to increase this too :D

### How to solve this?

Do I add some entry to `.tmux.conf` or set global settings ?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> and learn what your <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> does:

```
C-b q       Display pane numbers
```

But `Display pane numbers` is just a description, not really useful in further investigation. In a shell inside tmux run:

```
tmux list-keys | grep q
```

and one of the lines will be:

```
bind-key    -T prefix       q                    display-panes
```

This is useful and points us to the `display-panes` tmux command. Now check the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#displayp), it states:

> `display-panes [-bN] [-d duration] [-t target-client] [template]`
> (alias: `displayp`)
> Display a visible indicator of each pane shown by *target-client*. […] The indicator is closed when a key is pressed (unless `-N` is given) or *duration* milliseconds have passed. If `-d` is not given, `display-panes-time` is used. A duration of zero means the indicator stays until a key is pressed. […]

[And](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#display-panes-time):

> `display-panes-time time`
> Set the time in milliseconds for which the indicators shown by the `display-panes` command appear.

This leads us to two solutions:

1. Either re-bind <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> so it includes `-d 2000`. In `~/.tmux.conf` you do this with:

   ```
   bind-key -T prefix q display-panes -d 2000
   ```
2. Or keep using the current binding (without `-d`) and adjust `display-panes-time`. In `~/.tmux.conf`:

   ```
   set -g display-panes-time 2000
   ```

Keep in mind the file is parsed when a tmux server starts. To affect your already running server do one of the following:

- reload the altered file in tmux:
  <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source-file ~/.tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- reload the altered file by invoking a tmux client in a shell inside tmux:

  ```
  tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
  ```
- type the chosen tmux command in tmux, e.g.:
  <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`bind-key -T prefix q display-panes -d 2000`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- pass the chosen command by invoking a tmux client in a shell inside tmux:

  ```
  tmux bind-key -T prefix q display-panes -d 2000
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> key is bound to `display-panes`, which has both a `display-panes-time` setting and accepts a "duration" option. Set the option to whatever time (ms) you like:

```
set -g display-panes-time 200
```

(Specify zero to have the numbers remain until a keypress.)

If that weren't available, you could rebind the key with the option specified:

```
bind-key q display-panes -d 200
```

You can also tell tmux to *always* show each pane's index (and title) inline as part of its border:

```
set -g pane-border-status top
```